# Azure Function response called from Logic App doubling up linebreaks

Tags: azure-functions, format, azure-logic-apps

Within Azure Function I have a process removing lines from plain text.  When running from Postman the response is as expected:

```
{
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Content": ":20:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n:25:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n:28C:XXXXX/XXX\n-"
}
```

However when Function is called from Logic App the line breaks double up unexpectedly in the response:

```
{
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Content": ":20:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n:25:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n:28C:XXXXX/XXX\n\n-"
}
```

Content-Type is set to "application/json; charset=utf-8".

What can I do to prevent the Logic App request from doubling up the line breaks?

Comment: Hang on … what does your original payload into the function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, This was working fine for me without any doubling of lines in logic apps. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var myObj = new {IsSuccess= true,
    StatusCode= 200,
    Content=":20:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n:25:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n:28C:XXXXX/XXX\n\n-"};
    var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

[image]

> What can I do to prevent the Logic App request from doubling up the line breaks?

In this particular case you can manipulate the data before sending it as response using `Replace` method.